# No files present after downloading a zipped file from Github

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

Github shows the size of the file as 2.2GB but when I download or import the project, the size is just 135KB for that file and am unable to extract it. It says it is either damaged or empty. I did lfs upload while pushing. Someone please help here.

Comment: Sorry, probably I misunderstood the question. Are you using git lfs? If so, please add the relevant tag.

Comment: Yes @DaemonPainter , I have used git lfs and uploaded the zipped files. Now zipped files have the files. When I download them, it comes corrupted. But Github shows the size of the zipped file as 2.2GB which means it really has some content. I have executed git lfs fetch --all and it says "No object exists in the server: [404]". I'm stuck and have got bruises by banging my head over this!